# Show class if input:invalid:not(:empty) in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

how to add a has-error class if input **:invalid:not(:empty)** in vue.js?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" id="loginEmail" name="loginEmail" v-model="loginEmail" required>
  <label for="loginEmail">email</label>
  <div class="icon form">
    <icon name="email"></icon>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" id="loginEmail" name="loginEmail" v-model="loginEmail" required>
  <label for="loginEmail">email</label>
  <div class="icon form" v-bind:class="loginEmail.checkValidity ? 'has-success' : 'has-error'">
    <icon name="email"></icon>
  </div>
</div>
```

Vue

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    loginEmail: ''
  }
})
```

This solution shows a class, but when I change anything in the input, no reflesh. This **has-error** class is here permanent.

**SOLVED**

```
input:not(:valid):not(:placeholder-shown) + label + .icon.form {
  svg {
    stroke: red;
  }
}
```

The solution was so embarrassingly simple. I'm ashamed not to think of it. Finally, it was resolved by CSS without using vue.js

Comment: Shouldn't it be `loginEmail.checkValidity()` with parentheses since it is a function call?

Comment: No, checkValidity is function from JS and works without () for me.

Answer (score 0):

To add a `style class` dynamically you need to pass it as `object`

**Note** Object key get added as class to element if the respective `value` is `true`

```
<div :class = { 'has-error':loginEmail.checkValidity , 'has-success': true  } >
```

Reference to Official vue docs - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: Dont work, div have has-success class permament. I want no class if input is empty, has-error class if is invalid and has-success if is valid

Comment: You need to create a `computed` property to reflect your matches. I just tried to show you how can you add a class dynamically

Comment: Oh I'm not very proficient at this, could you write this method for me?

Comment: Ahh -  That will sound more like to do your homework, Just show you the right way to have classes dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write something like

```
computed: {
    checkProperty: function () {
      if(checkValidity === true) return true;
      return false;
    }
  }
```

then in your html you can write

```
<div :class = { 'has-error':!checkProperty , 'has-success': checkProperty} >
```

Comment: While this does solve the problem, it's difficult to see why. Please consider editing your answer to include an explanation of what you changed, why you changed it, and why it solves the problem.

Comment: I don't know why, but this doesn't work. The class has-success is here permanently

Comment: Ok, maybe I miss something.
Can you show me what is your loginEmail.checkValidity ?

Comment: Its just a checkValidity() function from pure JS. nothing written on my side

Comment: Ok, maybe the most easiest thing to do here is to always display the has-success and add the has-error AFTER in case your checkValidity return a false


`<div class="has-success" :class = { 'has-error' : !checkProperty }>`

Comment: Could it add a has-empty class if the input is empty? So has-empty, has-error (invalid) and has-success (valid)